# Ctrl Left click in Android Studio shows multi declaration of same variable with @+

Tags: android-studio

in Android Studio 1.3.1 and even before that, I noticed that Ctrl+left_click in the java code R.id.myET takes me to the location where this attribute is located in the xml file.
But sometimes it gives more than one choice, particularly when there is an EditText which has an @+id/myET and the same id is used in another EditText attribute

```
android:nextFocusForward="@+id/myET
```

one listing for each @+, it is only when I remove the "+" from the nextFocusForward attribute that it will take me to @+/myET, but that will break the nextFocusForward functionality.
How can I get nextFocusForward to work without having to add "+", or get Android Studio to take me to view myET and not to the view whose nextFocusForward attribute is set to @+id/myET?

Comment: I think the scope of the id is a package, so if you have the mulitple + definitions of an id in a package, that could be a problem.

Comment: select the id, then right-click "find usage"